# grammar structure about Clause

Tags: relative-clauses, optional-that

Could help to explain below sentence structure?

> "The insect repellent that prevents bug bites has its shortcomings."

Because I saw "**The insect repellent**" to be the subject and "t**he prevents bug bites**" be the clause, but next coming " **has its shortcomings**", so it confused me.

Thanks,

Comment: I'm not sure why you are confused. Without *has its shortcomings* there would be no verb, and it would not be a complete sentence. What is it about the end of the sentence that seems strange to you?

Comment: Hi Jason, does the 'prevents' not verb? I think 'prevents' that be the verb in the subject. Does my realize incorrect?

Comment: The subject is the whole noun phrase "The insect repellent [that prevents bug bites]". The bracketed bit is a clause with its own verb, but it's an optional modifier that is part of the subject. The "main" verb is "has", which is head of the predicate verb phrase "has its shortcomings".

Comment: Hi Bill, I get it, thanks for your explain.